# Pusher-js getting error net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

Tags: reactjs, pusher-js

Im trying to connect to pusher in a react app and i keep getting the error net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT. I've looked up the error and its generally associated with add ons, but i tried removing all my google chrome add ons but its still not working.

I connect to pusher like this:

```
const pusher = new Pusher(PUSHER_APP_KEY, {
  appId: PUSHER_APP_ID,
  cluster: PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
  secret: PUSHER_APP_SECRET,
  forceTLS: true
});
```

I've tested on Mozilla and Chrome but and there is no error on the Mozilla browser

Comment: For me, uBlock was the issue but it could also be built-in Chrome tracker blocking, have you checked your Chrome privacy settings?